# How does the linker know where is the definition of an extern function?

Tags: c++, c, extern, keil

I read a few posts and concluded that extern tells compiler that "This function exists, but the code for it is somewhere else. Don't panic." But how does the linker know where the function is defined.

My CASE:-
I am working on Keil uvision 4. There is a header file grlib.h and the main function is in grlib_demo.c(it includes grlib.h). Now, there is a function GrCircleDraw() which is defined in Circle.c and called in grlib_demo.c, there is also a statement

> extern void GrCircleDraw(all arguments);

in grlib.h. My query is how linker knows where the definition of GrCircleDraw() is since Circle.c is not included in grlib.h and grlib_demo.c

Note :- The files grlib.h and Circle.c are in the same folder. The code runs successfully.

Comment: Welcome to the magic of the linker

Comment: At one level, the compiler doesn't know; it is the linker's job to find the functions.  The linker knows because you tell it where to look for it — either in object files on the command line, or in libraries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple answer is that "the compiler doesn't need to know, but the linker has to be able to find it". Through multiple `.o` files, or through libraries, the linker has to be able to find a single definition of the `GrCircleDraw` function.

Comment: Crap, I wrote Compiler by mistake, of course it has to be linker. But then linker has to know where the definition is in some form. In my code Circle.c (which includes the definition is not added anywhere). How is that possible that the linker still finds it?

Comment: The linker has to find at least one definition of `GrCircleDraw`. Normally, it will ignore any extra definitions after the first, but it will object if the definitions are in two object files, or if you're linking with a static library and the object file in the library that contains the second definition is also needed to satisfy some other symbol; it will complain about double definition.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There is no second definition. My query is how linker finds even that one definition.

Comment: @AnkitGupta: If your code links successfully, then you have almost certainly informed the linker about `Circle.o` in some way. There's no magic here.

Comment: @GregHewgill But, Circle.c is not even compiled, how can we have circle.o then

Comment: @AnkitGupta: So you're telling us that: (1) There is a `circle.c` but it's not compiled; (2) the *only* definition of `GrCircleDraw` is in `circle.c`; and (3) your program compiles, links, and runs successfully. I don't believe all of those are true. In particular, I would suspect (2), and that there really is another definition of `GrCircleDraw`, perhaps in a library file that you're linking with.

Comment: @GregHewgill But we can have only one definition of an extern function, since we have a definition in circle.c can't we conclude that there is no other definition?

Comment: You haven't shown any evidence that you have any other definition (other than the claim that your program links successfully). The linker may allow you to supply two definitions, one in a *library* and one in an *object file*, and it will choose the one in the object file in preference to the library. But, that depends on your linker.

Comment: @GregHewgill yes, the grlib.lib is included in my project. How can I check if this library file has definition of GrCircleDraw.

Comment: Your linker should come with some utilities that help with things like that. I think the Visual C++ tool for that is called `dumpbin.exe` but you haven't said which compiler toolchain you are using. Another approach is to ask your linker to create a map file output, which shows a lot of detailed information about how the linker resolved your program.

Comment: @AnkitGupta Well since `circle.c` *isn't part of your program* (assuming you didn't link circle.o) the compiler and linker don't care about it! You can only have one definition of `GrCircleDraw` *in the program*.

Answer (score 11):

When you compile a .o file in the [ELF format](https://web.archive.org/web/20150509130428/http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armlink/armlink_pge1396357653538.htm), you have many things on the `.o` file such as:

- a `.text` section containing the code;
- `.data`, `.rodata`, `.rss` sections containing the global variables;
- a `.symtab` containing the list of the symbols (functions, global variables and others) in the `.o` (and their location in the file) as well as the symbols used by the `.o` file;
- sections such as `.rela.text` which are list of relocations -- these are the modifications that the link editor (and/or the dynamic linker) will have to make in order to link the differents parts of you program together.

### On the caller side

Let's compile a simple C file:

```
extern void GrCircleDraw(int x);

int foo()
{
  GrCircleDraw(42);
  return 3;
}

int bla()
{
  return 2;
}
```

with:

```
gcc -o test.o test.c -c
```

(I'm using the native compiler of my system but it will work quite the  same when cross-compiling to ARM).

You can look at the content of your .o file with:

```
readelf -a test.o
```

In the symbol table, you will find:

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 10 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
[...]
     8: 0000000000000000    21 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 foo
     9: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND GrCircleDraw
    10: 0000000000000015    11 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 bla
```

There is one symbol for our `foo` functions and one for `bla`. The value field give their location within the `.text` section.

There is one symbol for the used symbol `GrCircleDraw`: it is undefined because this functions is not defined in this `.o` file but remains to be found elsewhere.

In the relocation table for the `.text` section (`.rela.text`) you find:

```
Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0x260 contains 1 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
00000000000a  000900000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 GrCircleDraw - 4
```

This address is within `foo`: the link editor will patch the instruction at this address with the address of the `GrCircleDraw` function.

### On the callee side

Now let's compile ourself an implementation of `GrCircleDraw`:

```
void GrCircleDraw(int x)
{

}
```

Let's look at it's symbol table:

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 9 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
[...]
     8: 0000000000000000     9 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 GrCircleDraw
```

It has an entry for `GrCircleDraw` defining its location within its `.text` section.

### Linking them together

So when the link editor combines both files together it knowns:

- which functions is defined in which `.o` file and their locations;
- where in the code of the caller it must update with the address of the callee.

Comment: Can't believe no upvotes until me just now. This is a very well-crafted answer and I for one am glad to see the ELF breakdown like this.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler is placing just the name of the `extern` function into the `.obj` file. Compiler does not need to know more about it.

When you start linking, it is your responsibility as a developer to give all necessary object files and library files to the linker. Linker will arrange all these functions into a binary. If you do not specify the right libraries or `.obj` files, the linking will simply fail with `unresolved blah-blah`.

Default libraries are typically included implicitly. This complicates things and creates illusions. You can always specify that you do not want any implicit libraries and include everything explicitly. Unfortunately every system does this in its own way.

Comment: the code in question is a sample code. All I need to know is how Linker knows where the definition of GrCircleDraw() is, since Circle.c is not included in any of the files.

Comment: Since the prototype of your function is in `grlib.h`, most likely the body of this function is in `grlib.lib` or `grlib.a`. Look into log of your build or into the `.map` file. They might give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Linking usually happens this way: The command line is iterated over and every argument given is

1. used directly if it is an object file,
2. used in the extent needed (=to fulfill all references which are unresolved till now).

At the end, every reference has to be fulfilled in order to successfully link. The order of lines given at the linker command line is important.